# Combining, Handling and Serializing Lists in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, list

I m trying to craft my response from a webmethod in form of JSON from lists

First List properties

```
Public Class DataRes
    Public Property RecID As Integer
    Public Property filenum As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property msgcode As String
    Public Property msgtitle As String
    Public Property msg As String
    Public Property PartnerData As List(Of PartnerData)
End Class
```

My second List properties

```
 Public Class PartnerData
    Public Property RecID As Integer
    Public Property PrtStatus As Integer
    Public Property ptfilenum As Integer
    Public Property prfilenum As Integer
End Class
```

I fill the those lists as in the following code respectively

```html
Dim Ptdata As New List(Of DataRes)()
 Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While sdr.Read()
                        Ptdata.Add(New DataRes() With { _
                         .RecID = sdr("RecID").ToString(), _
                         .filenum = sdr("filenum").ToString(), _
                         .name = sdr("name").ToString() _
                        })
                    End While
                End Using
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Ptdata)


Dim Prtdata As New List(Of PartnerData)()
 Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While sdr.Read()
                        Prtdata.Add(New PartnerData() With { _
                         .prfilenum = sdr("PrtFilenum").ToString(), _
                         .PrtStatus = sdr("PrtStatus").ToString(), _
                         .ptfilenum = sdr("PtFilenum").ToString(), _
                         .RecID = sdr("RecID").ToString() _
                        })
                    End While
                End Using
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PartnerData)
```

I tested both lists and I m getting the desired outcome from each

**I m Trying to combine them and I tried the following,**

1. Dim combined = Ptdata.Concat(Prtdata).ToList()
   and I got this error,

> unable to cast object of type 'system.collections.generic.list`1

2. Dim combined = Ptdata.AddRange(Prtdata).ToList()
   and I got this error,

> Expression does not produce a value.

My target JSON Would be something like this

```
{
"PtRegData": {
    "RecID": "1277",
    "filenum": "15090248",
    "name": "Ahmad",

    "PartnerData": [{
        "RecID": 2383,
        "PrtStatus": 1
    }, {
        "RecID": 3387,
        "PrtStatus": 0
    }, {
        "RecID": 3388,
        "PrtStatus": 0
    }]
}}
```

**Plus how can I add a name to the list before I serialize it?**

**Edit**

```html
 Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While sdr.Read()
                        Ptdata.Add(New DataRes() With { _
                         .RecID = sdr("RecID").ToString(), _
                         .filenum = sdr("filenum").ToString(), _
                         .name = sdr("name").ToString(), _
                         .msgcode = sdr("msgcode").ToString(), _
                         .msgtitle = sdr("msgtitle").ToString(), _
                         .msg = sdr("msg").ToString() _
                        })
                    End While
                End Using
                
                 Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While sdr.Read()
                        Prtdata.Add(New PartnerData() With { _
                         .prfilenum = sdr("PrtFilenum").ToString(), _
                         .PrtStatus = sdr("PrtStatus").ToString(), _
                         .ptfilenum = sdr("PtFilenum").ToString(), _
                         .RecID = sdr("RecID").ToString() _
                        })
                    End While
                    For Each p In Ptdata
                        p.PartnerData.AddRange(Prtdata.Where(Function(c) c.ptfilenum = p.filenum))
                    Next
                End Using
```

Comment: You would need one item type to have a property that is a list of the other item type and you would then need to populate that collection for each item from the other list.  You can't just stick the two lists together end-to-end and expect it to magically create that relationship.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, Thanks for the response, I updated on of the classes and I m still getting the same error ,,, unable to cast object of type 'system.collections.generic.list`1

Comment: Did you write code to add the `PartnerData` objects to the `PartnerData` collection of the `DataRes` object they are related to?

Comment: I m pretty new to lists, please excuse my ignorance,,,,, I added this prop. ....... Public Property PartnerData As List(Of PartnerData) to the DataRes

Comment: That property won't be populated of its own volition.  You have to write to code to populate it for each item.  I'll provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you have these types:

```
Public Class Parent

    Public Property ParentId As Integer

    Public Property ParentName As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Children As New List(Of Child)

End Class


Public Class Child

    Public Property ChildId As Integer

    Public Property ParentId As Integer

    Public Property ChildName As String

End Class
```

The names and properties don't really matter.  Only the parent/child relationship is important.  The parent type has a property that is a collection of the child type.  Assuming that you have two lists of parent and child items:

```
Dim parents As New List(Of Parent)
Dim children As New List(Of Child)
```

you can populate the `Children` property of each `Parent` object like so:

```
For Each p In parents
    p.Children.AddRange(children.Where(Function(c) c.ParentId = p.ParentId))
Next
```

If you prefer the long-hand version:

```
For Each p In parents
    For Each c In children
        If c.ParentId = p.ParentId Then
            p.Children.Add(c)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

EDIT: Older versions of VB (earlier than 2017) may not support the syntax shown above for a read-only property.  The code below should work in all versions:

```
Public Class Parent

    Public _children As New List(Of Child)

    Public Property ParentId As Integer

    Public Property ParentName As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Children As List(Of Child)
        Get
            Return _children
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: I understand, Thanks but in my case the two lists have no records in common, how can I just attach the outcome without creating the relationship between the properties like in c.ParentId = p.ParentId

Comment: Sorry if I m not explaining myself properly but my JSON above might be more useful

Comment: Your JSON indicates that a `DataRes` object is the parent for related `PartnerData` objects.  If you have no way to identify which are related to which then how can you possibly output JSON that shows those relationships?

Comment: I updated the code under **Edit** section, I got this error,, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.,,, both list have c.ptfilenum = p.filenum kind of relation

Comment: Does the parent property that contain the child's list have to be " Public ReadOnly Property"? because .NET is not accepting it without a getter

Comment: I m really sorry, I m still getting the same error,,, Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: On what line of code? Which reference on that line is null? Did you actually create a `List` as I did in the example code?

Comment: I am getting null for the child. c.ptfilenum,,, I can see the value of p.filenum

Comment: I will post here both list outcomes, separatly

Comment: Parent List,,,,,, [{"RecID":1277,"filenum":15090248,"name":"Ahmad Morsi abdul fattah Abu Maizerasdasd","msgcode":"info","msgtitle":"Succsessful SQL Transaction","msg":"Record has been updated succsessfully","PartnerData":null}],,,,,,,,,,,,,, Child list,,,,,,,,,[{"RecID":2383,"PrtStatus":0,"ptfilenum":15090248,"prfilenum":13090701},{"RecID":3387,"PrtStatus":1,"ptfilenum":15090248,"prfilenum":15120996},{"RecID":3388,"PrtStatus":1,"ptfilenum":15090248,"prfilenum":170227111},{"RecID":3416,"PrtStatus":1,"ptfilenum":15090248,"prfilenum":11021602}]

Comment: they both share "15090248"

Comment: What I m doing is ,,, 1. populate parent, 2. populate child, 3, join them by the code you gave me, 4. trying to serialize and return it back

Comment: it worked finally,,, something wrong was with my select statement, thanks so much